# Cannot find module eyes

Tags: node.js, vows

I have installed vows using 'npm install vows' and made sure that i have 'eyes' but running 'npm install eyes' in the terminal. I have checked that there a eyes folder in the node_modules folder in the local user. But when i run some test using 'vows' keyword, i get this error for the eyes module. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling vows and eyes multiple times, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me fix this.

module.js:340
    throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'eyes'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/bin/vows:32:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:487:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the location problem.
you installed from a different source of your npm, node.js other than the default one.

You may run:

```
whereis eyes
where is npm
```

in your terminal to check your install location.